# How to copy list of lists from python without last elements from each list

Tags: python, list, copy

How can I copy list of lists and delete last element from each in one step ? I can do something like this, but would like to learn to do it in one step:

```
test2 = [["A","A","C"],
         ["C","A"],
         ["A","B","C","A"]]

import copy
test3 = copy.deepcopy(test2)
for item in test3:
    del item[-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one step, you'll want to use a list comprehension. Assuming your lists are two dimensional only and the sublists composed of scalars, you can use the slicing syntax to create a copy.

```
>>> [x[:-1] for x in test2]
[['A', 'A'], ['C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

If your sublists contain mutable/custom objects, call `copy.deepcopy` inside the expression.

```
>>> [copy.deepcopy(x[:-1]) for x in test2]
[['A', 'A'], ['C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Comment: Note, `deepcopy` has a default deepcopy behavior for custom classes. It is overridable with the `__deepcopy__` hook, but isn't strictly required (and in my experience, rarely necessary toimplement)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay, thank you. I was under the impression it'd throw errors.